# VS Code installed in Windows comes up as running under WSL Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: visual-studio-code

I installed VS Code in windows,  but it comes up as running under WSL Ubuntu 18.04.
I don't want to run in the linux subsystem, but in windows proper.
Uninstalling and reinstalling does not change this.
Uninstalling and deleting all vscode file and folders in /users  does not change this.

Answer (score 3):

Try going to the bottom left of your window and press on the `WSL: Ubuntu-18.04` button.

[image: The WSL: Ubuntu-18.04 button]

After pressing the button, go to the top center of the window and choose `Close Remote Connection`.

[image: Close Remote Connection]

After that, VS Code should stop auto-connecting to the WSL Ubuntu system every time when you open it (I tested myself and it worked on my computer).

Comment: Thanks. I tried that.  Then I get a window in the lower right that says: "Extension 'Remote - WSL' is required to open the remote window. Do you want to install the extension?"    The python extension will not install - it asks to install on remote.     fwiw my python installation is miniconda 3.7.6

Comment: I think you can try install the "Remote - WSL" extension first, so that you can try out the steps I listed in the above. After finishing the above steps and make sure that VS Code is not running under WSL, you can uninstall the "Remote - WSL" extension

Comment: ok, so remote seems to be running (it says "Welcome = bin [WSL:Ubuntu 18.04] at the top of the window.  But there is nothing that was wsl in the lower left corner and nothing to click on there

Comment: Hmm that's weird. You can press "Ctrl + Shift + P" to bring up the command palette, then type "Remote: Close Remote Connection" and run this command. This should close the remote connection to your WSL system. Alternatively, you may go to the bottom bar and right click on it. It would bring up a menu to show what buttons to display in the bottom bar. See if there's an option called "Remote Host" and if so, enable to it. This should display the WSL connection button on the bottom left.

Comment: I wrote too soon.  I still don't seem to be accessing an interpreter in windows.   The instructions say "Select your Python interpreter by clicking on the status bar",  but clicking in the status bar does not show me any intepreters.   I can't start a debug session.